# Am I creating an undefined nil method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Everything is working properly except for when I want to check if a post belongs to a user_id.

What I am basically trying to achieve is to hide the delete post button so that other users can't delete it.

I am still new to ruby on rails when I did my first project I added an if statement that checks whether it belongs to the user_id or not. Now I am trying to do the same but I keep on getting the NoMethodError

Profile code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <% if @post.user_id == current_user.id %>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <%= render '/components/post_form' %>
                </div>
            <%end%>
        <%end%>
    </div>
</div>
```

Post controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    #new post
    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end
    #create post
    def create
        @post = Post.new(posts_params)
        @post.user_id = current_user.id
        respond_to do |f|
            if (@post.save)
                f.html {redirect_to :back}
            else
                f.html {redirect_to :back, notice: "An error happened while submitting your post. Please try again."}
            end         
        end
    end
    #show post 
    def show
        if (User.find_by_username(params[:id]))
            @post = params[:id]
        end
    end
    #destroy post
    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to :back
    end
    #private
    private
        def posts_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:user_id, :content)
        end

        def find_post
            @post = Post.find(params[:id])          
        end

end
```

Pages controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def home
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def profile
    if (User.find_by_username(params[:id]))
        @username = params[:id]
    else
        redirect_to root_path, :notice => "user not found"
    end

    @posts = Post.all.where( "user_id = ?", User.find_by_username(params[:id]) )
    @newPost = Post.new
  end

  def explore
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

Post schema:

```
  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

**Update**

Error I am getting:

```
NoMethodError in Pages#profile
```

Full trace:

```
app/views/pages/profile.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_pages_profile_html_erb___203732305_53267256'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

**Update**

Form partial:

```
<%= simple_form_for @newPost do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.text_field :content, autofocus: true %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you post your detailed error code?

Comment: @JeffersonChoi, I updated my question

Comment: User.find_by_username(params[:id])

Shouldn't that contain a .id at the end?

Comment: FYI: `@posts = Post.all.where` is redundant, just use `@posts = Post.where(...)`.

Comment: Also, `@posts = Post.all.where( "user_id = ?", User.find_by_username(params[:id]) )
` is all backwards. You should be using Rails associations to achieve this: `@user = User.where(...); @posts = @user.posts`.

Comment: I tried it before. If i put User.find_by_username(params[:id]) without "== current_user.id" the delete button will appear to everyone and if I add the current_user.id the button disappears for everyone even the user.

Comment: he's not saying remove that, he's saying you can improve the code in your controller. please see and try my answer below.

Comment: I did, it did not fix it

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <% if @post.user_id == current_user.id %>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <%= render '/components/post_form' %>
                </div>
            <%end%>
        <%end%>
    </div>
</div>
```

with this:

```
<div class="container">
   <% if user_signed_in? && @newPost.present? && @newPost.user_id == current_user.id %>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-5">
         <%= render '/components/post_form' %>
      </div>
    </div>
 <%end%>
</div>
```

notice in your controller you defined `@newPost`, but your view is trying to use `@post` which doesnt exist.

Also you may want to pass `@newPost` into the partial, like so:

```
<%= render '/components/post_form', object: @newPost %>
```

Comment: It did remove the error but it also removed the form to the user as well

Comment: ok, to debug you need to check 3 things for the "if" statement: 1) user_signed_in? is true, 2) `@newPost` is actually set, 3) the user created the post. The issue might also be in your partial, please can i see "/components/post_form" - that will need to reference `@newPost` internally one way or another

Comment: I'd use debugger or pry to identify what data isn't available.